# Nvim is not highlighting (bold) for my specified pattern

Tags: vim, neovim

I'm trying to have the following syntax highlighting, but the bold between the two astrix is not showing up. The first few lines of my ~/.nvimrc is as follows:

```
highlight Bold cterm=bold
highlight bg ctermbg=Gray

match Bold /\*.*\*/
match bg /#[^#]*#/
```

The result is like this:

[image]

How do I fix it so that * NOT MATCHING * is bolded in the terminal?

Comment: cannot be reproduced with vim 8.1 which terminal do you use?

Comment: I should have added I'm using neovim, `nvim`

Comment: Which color theme are you using? I don't get bold highlighting with `onedark`, but if I start with `nvim -u NONE`, I see bold text. Plain `vim` with no config works too.

Comment: try to set it to `ctermbg=Gray` i bet it does match? see `:Highlights` and have a look at bold? is it overwritten?

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo `Highlights` is not an editor command.

Comment: @PhilippLudwig sry I meant `:highlight`